# Setting up Data Level Application Alerts in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Solutions are available for providing alerts when any job fails in SQL Server.

Is there any solution available for setting up data level alerts - for e.g.

1. if data hasn't updated in USER tables for lets say 2 hours, we get an ALERT
2. if any USER table, specific column lets say has aggregate of more than 100% (which is not right) then we get an alert
3. if any specific column which should not have value (lets say greater than 10), then we get an alert

We can create a table for this type of alerts and then run may be any SSIS package or TSQL every 15 mins - and anything which doesnt match the benchmark value set for alerts we get email.

Is any aware of any solution developed for this type of need

Regards

Comment: Set up a SQL Agent job that runs periodically, checks for these conditions and sends alerts as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not any built-in feature that does exactly this.  I'm also not aware of an off-the-shelf product that does what you're looking for.

However, based on the description of your requirements, it seems like a SQL Server Agent job would work really well!

Set up an agent job that runs every 15 minutes, has steps that run the different checks you're interested in, and sends emails to your support team using [`sp_send_dbmail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

To get started, find the "SQL Server Agent" node in SSMS, right click on "Jobs," and choose "New Job."  There's a detailed walkthrough of all the options here: [Create a Job | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-2017)